# How to convert 'last name, first name' format to First Name Last Name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, parsing, substring, charindex

I am using MS SQL Server.  I have a column, 'CUSTOMER_NAME'.  Names are in Last Name, First Name format and some include suffix info such as 'Jr' or 'II'.  I was using the below to split into two separate columns, one for first name and one for last name.  The problem I run into is with the suffix info.  It splits into both first and last name columns.  Example 'Smith Jr, Joe' splits as 'Jr, Joe' in first_name and 'Smith Jr' as Last_Name.  How can I modify this to correct the first_name output?

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME,
       LEFT(CUSTOMER_NAME,CHARINDEX(', ',CUSTOMER_NAME + ' ')-1)  AS LAST_NAME,
       SUBSTRING(CUSTOMER_NAME,CHARINDEX(' ',CUSTOMER_NAME + ' ')+1,LEN(CUSTOMER_NAME)) AS FIRST_NAME
FROM   table_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modification below will cover both scenarios i.e. With and without suffix.

```
   SUBSTRING(CUSTOMER_NAME,CHARINDEX(', ',CUSTOMER_NAME + ' ')+2,LEN(CUSTOMER_NAME)) AS FIRST_NAME
```

Comment: Hi @nation161r if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.